# function-like macro with the same name as an object-like macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to have in C something like:

```
#define MACRO_EX 333

#define MACRO_EX(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? : (X) : (Y))
```

Can they coexist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) says (ISO/IEC 9899:1999, §6.10.3, 2):

> An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another
>   #define preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro
>   definition and the two replacement lists are identical. Likewise, an identifier currently
>   defined as a function-like macro shall not be redefined by another #define
>   preprocessing directive unless the second definition is a function-like macro definition
>   that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are
>   identical.

So the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

No. A function-like (with args) and an object-like macro (no args) can not be defined with the same name (in standardese, attempting to do so violates a **shall not** rule, which means the compiler is required to diagnose it). However, C99 specifies variadic macros (taking 1 or more args). Maybe that'll do what you want?

You are free to `#undef MACRO_EX` and redefine it with args, if that solves your problem. But it can be used only with or without args.

Comment: No . I had the problem that the macro was defined function-like, but was used as object-like and I had the error of not being defined and that confused me. Furthermore I did not really how it was defined since there are a lot of dependent compilation flags in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
warning: "MACRO_EX" redefined [enabled by default]
```

In this program,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define MACRO_EX 333
    #define MACRO_EX(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? : (X) : (Y))

    int main()
    {

    printf("\n %d  %d\n", MACRO_EX, MACRO_EX(10,20));
    printf("\n %d  %d\n", MACRO_EX);

    return 0;
    }
```

Im getting

```
 warning: "MACRO_EX" redefined [enabled by default]
 note: this is the location of the previous definition
 In function ‘main’:
 error: ‘MACRO_EX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
```

If I comment one macro & it's usage then works fine :)

**But As per C99 Std**

***6.10.3***

An identifier currently defined as an `object-like` macro shall not be redefined by another #define pre-processing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. Likewise, an identifier currently defined as a `function-like` macro shall not be redefined by another #define    pre-processing directive unless the second definition is a function-like macro definition that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are identical.

I tried the same code by compiling with `-std=c99` still getting same error.

Comment: What if this is a special feature/bug of that particular compiler?

Comment: In C99, they supported/allowed it seems.

Comment: No, they are not. "shall not be redefined except ...".

Comment: ...."that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are identical".. It means that,  with different no.of args, same macro name can be used.

Comment: The part "has the same number ... of parameters" means you cannot. Bsides, the OP wants to redefine an objetc-like macro by a function-like macro.

Answer (score 0):

see

http://codepad.org/0nfvOGTl

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MACRO_EX 333

#define MACRO_EX(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? : (X) : (Y))


int main()
{

printf("valud is %d",MACRO_EX);
return 0;
}
```

error

```
Line 0: warning: "MACRO_EX" redefined
Line 0: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In function 'main':
Line 10: error: 'MACRO_EX' undeclared (first use in this function)
Line 10: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Line 10: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Comment: What if this is a special feature/bug of that particular compiler?